# Meaning of colon inside parenthesises

Tags: antlr

What meaning does the expression `(: .)` have inside the ANTLR-rule

```
message
   : COLON (: .)*?
   ;
```

at https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/stacktrace/StackTrace.g4#L79

?

I can't any doc reference to colons being allowed inside rules. Shouldn't the `:` inside the parenthesises be replaced by `COLON` in this case?

*Update*:

Are these cases also left-overs from removal of `options`?;

```
grammars-v4/antlr/antlr3/examples/Verilog3.g(548,13): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `'else'` at offset 12136
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(696,18): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `logical_operator` at offset 13302
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(700,17): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `DOUBLESTAR` at offset 13359
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(1087,25): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `identifier` at offset 20396
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(1232,9): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `relational_operator` at offset 22963
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(1310,9): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `shift_operator` at offset 24300
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(1351,32): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `adding_operator` at offset 24999
grammars-v4/vhdl/vhdl.g4(1497,16): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `multiplying_operator` at offset 28078
grammars-v4/pascal/pascal.g4(439,38): Warning: ignoring colon with no effect, token `ELSE` at offset 7347
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no meaning and should be removed. My guess is that the grammar is converted from ANTLR3 where the following was in the v3 version:

```
message
   : COLON (options{greedy=false;}: .)*
   ;
```

They removed the `options{greedy=false;}` part without removing the `:`. To match ungreedy in v4, the `?` was introduced. You can also remove the parenthesis:

```
message
   : COLON .*?
   ;
```

This should be a warning for you: the grammar is not well tested, and the fact that a rule ends with a `.*?` is always a bit suspicious to me (often there are better ways to match such a rule). There are also more things I don't like about this grammar (not necessarily wrong, but things I consider bad practice). Be cautious using this in a production environment!

Comment: My own analysis tool found more cases with trailing colons. I pasted the output in my original post above. Should these colons be removed aswell?

Comment: Yes, all of those `:`'s you linked to can (should) be removed.